# How to get index of minimum value of all max_values sliced from another list using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, max, minimum

I have two arrays

```
B = [[250, 100], [200, 120], [150, 150], [150, 80], [100, 150], [150, 250]]
A = [[1, 1], [1, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 1], [0.8, 0.3], [0.5, 0.9]]
```

first step is to recieve items with all max [0] values in A array and their indexes

```
a0 = [[1, 1], [1, 0.5]]
max_a_index_0 = [0, 1]
```

then we get items from B array by indexes of recieved max values

```
b0 = [[250, 100], [200,120]]
```

after that we select the item with minimum value and get it index from original B array.

```
max_b0_index_0 = 1
```

The same proccess with [1] elements:

```
b1 = [[250, 100], [150, 80]]
a1 = [[1, 1], [0.5, 1]]
max_a_index_1 = [0, 3]
max_b0_index_1 = 3
```

Update: Here is my code. Is there better way to do such calculations?

```
for n in range(2):
    a_max_0 = np.argwhere(np.array(A)[:,n] == np.amax(np.array(A)[:,n])).flatten().tolist()
    b_a_max_0 = [B[i] for i in range(len(A)) if i in a_max_0]
    b_min_0 = np.argwhere(np.array(b_a_max_0)[:,n] == np.amin(np.array(b_a_max_0)[:,n])).flatten().tolist()
    a_b_max_min_index = [a_max_0[i] for i in range(len(a_max_0)) if i in b_min_0]
    print(a_b_max_min_index)
```

Comment: Too confusing explanation

Comment: You ask no question

Comment: I asked the question in title: how can such task be solved using numpy.

Comment: We can make pandas dataframe then, sort values by max and then min and after that get indexes. But i wonder if there are any way to do this using numpy.